# Update foreground color of selected image in UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, uitabbaritem

I have changed the default blue color of some selected text with `setTitleTextAttributes.`
However, the image still becomes blue when selected.

[image]

How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use UIAppearance.

`[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]`];